# Display list of items rotated and vertical aligned in bottom

Tags: css, rotation, styles, vertical-alignment

Im having a list of texts on different length which should be firstlly rotated and than aligned in bottom. The space betwen them should be equally and not depended on the word length.

Below is an example

```css
#outer {
  line-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  width: max-content;

}

#text {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;

}
```

```html
  <div id="outer">
      <span id="text">My Vertical Text</span>
    <span id="text">My  Text</span>
    <span id="text">My Vertical Text</span>
    <span id="text">a</span>
    <span id="text">My Vertical Text number 4</span>
    <span id="text">helooo</span>
 
  </div>
```

Comment: The ids suppose to be unique, use `class` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.text {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <span class="text">My Vertical Text</span>
      <span class="text">My Text</span>
      <span class="text">My Vertical Text</span>
      <span class="text">A</span>
      <div class="text">My Vertical Text number 4</div>
      <span class="text">helooo</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).